# Plotting graph with categorical axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe, which I am aiming to plot both max data and min data on the same graph, using Month_Day as x-axis, but only printing 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', etc...

```
Month_Day  max  min
 0    Jan-01  243   86
 1    Jan-02  230   90
 2    Jan-03  233  104
 3    Jan-04  220   73
 4    Jan-05  224   71
```

but once I include the dates, it poped an error.

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2015','31/12/2015', freq='D')
plt.plot(tmax, '-r', tmin, '-b')
#plt.plot(dates, tmax, '-r', dates, tmin, '-b') <- this is the line i plot dates as axis
plt.fill_between(range(len(tmin)), tmin, tmax, facecolor='gray', alpha=0.25)
plt.grid(True)
```

gives the error:

```
error: ordinal must be >= 1
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: sorry for my stupid miss....

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xaxis.set_major_formatter()`.
Here's a simple example of this:

```
import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make up some data
x = [datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(180)]
y = [i+random.gauss(0,1) for i,_ in enumerate(x)]

p1 = plt.subplot(211)
p1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdate.DateFormatter('%b', None))

# plot
plt.plot(x,y)
# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

#### Output

[image]